# Multivalued property

Tags: magnolia

I would like to get a value for the multivalued property *validation*.

The code I used is as follows:

```
        println ("*** Listed are properties for the " +  childArea.getName() + " child: ***");
        while(propOfChildArea.hasNext())
        {
            Property pchildofarea = propOfChildArea.nextProperty();
             if (!pchildofarea.isMultiple()) {

                        String namechofarea = pchildofarea.getName();
                        String valchofarea = pchildofarea.getString();
                        println(String.format("|%-50s", "property_name:"+ namechofarea) + String.format("|%-50s"," property_value: " + valchofarea));

                    } else{
                        println("################here is a multiple property: "+ pchildofarea.getName());
                        Value[] value = pchildofarea.getValues();
                        println("value is:" + value[value.size()-1]);
                    }


        }
```

I would expect to get a value for this poperty but instead I get `org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.value.QValueValue@5c24b9c`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one does `getValues()` it actually fetches a Value object @see ->

```
javax.jcr.Value
```

On top of that, you should get the concrete value of the property and that depends on the expected property type. In general, you can fetch the value via `javax.jcr.Value#getString`

Cheers,

Hope that helps,